# Best way to avoid "isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)"-warning

Tags: perl, operators, warnings, equality

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.2;

my $c = 'f'; # could be a number too

if ( $c eq 'd' || $c == 9 ) {
    say "Hello, world!";
}
```

What is the best way, to avoid the 'Argument "f" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./perl.pl line 7.'-warning?
I suppose in this case I could use "eq" two times, but that doesn't look good.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';    

if ( $c eq 'd' || ( looks_like_number($c) && $c == 9 ) ) {
    say "Hello, world!";
}
```

You could also disable this category of warnings temporarily:

```
{
    no warnings 'numeric';
    # your code
}
```

Comment: works fine. Thanks!
Since I gotta use XMPP for debugging the permanent warnings are a very good reason to disable this kind for good.

Answer (score 19):

Not sure why you want to avoid the warning. The warning is telling you that there's a potential problem in your program.

If you're going to compare a number with a string that contains unknown data, then you're either going to have to use 'eq' for the comparison or clean up the data in some way so that you know it looks like a number.

Comment: You're right in principal, however the question is: how would one disable the messages. Perls differentiation between string and numeric comparisons is annoying at best. It doesn't seem to matter if the comparison is done through '==' or 'eq' so one might as well turn the warning off. In my eyes Eugene Y's answer is the one that counts for this question.

Comment: Given that it doesn't matter if the comparison is done through == or eq, the proper way is to use the string comparison operator to compare strings.  Turning off the warning is comparatively more work than simply using the right operator to begin with; not to mention that the entire basis for the question is the sketchy opinion that "eq" used twice "doesn't look good."  `$c` is a string, and there's no math involved here.  So treat it like a string, for heaven's sake, and just quote the nine. :)

Comment: This is so old answer, but I can't hold it: this answer is not in the spirit of Perl, as I see it. Perl was created so, that you could use your variables interchangeably (if such a word may exist in English). You can use a number as a string and a string as a number. Of course, there are places to have such precise control over variables, but also there are places, where you can distinguish your procedures by letting the same variable contain either a string or a number. In such case the warning does not have the purpose.

Comment: @w.k: Sounds like you're using Perl as an excuse you ignore good software engineering practices :-) Either you know what kind of data is in your variable (in which case you can choose the appropriate comparison operator) or you don't (in which case, I'd suggest, you really want to use string comparisons). I guess you could also use things like `looks_like_number()` to help you make the choice - but I can't remember if that existed when I wrote this answer in 2010.

Comment: @DaveCross Thank you for your answer. Actually, I try mostly to convince people, that Perl is in every aspect perfectly good language to implement good software engineering practices. And I agree, your answer is toward these practices. Still, using Perl in the context of the quick script I don't see anything wrong with using one variable both as a number or string, like a string being a success and a number signaling some failure, In such a context is lecturing good software practice a bit redundant for me and against the Perl's nature of solving quick problems.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious way to avoid a warning about comparing a non-numeric to a numeric is *not to do it*!  Warnings are there for your benefit - they should not be ignored, or worked around.

To answer what is the *best* way you need to provide more context - i.e. what does `$c` represent, and why is it necessary to compare it do `'d'` or `9` (and why not use `$c eq '9'`)?

Comment: Because what if $c eq "  9" or "9.0" or "009"? Best to use the Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number'; as eugene stated above.

Comment: that's what I asked him to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression to see if that is a number:

```
if(($num=~/\d/) && ($num >= 0) && ($num < 10))
{
    # to do thing number 
}
```