# Comparing empty string with number

Tags: perl

I have a global value:

```
my $gPrevious ='';

# main();
func();

sub func {
  my $localval = 52552;

  if ($gPrevious != $localval) {
      ------------
     x statements;
  }
}
```

Output:

> Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric ne (!=) at line x.

Why do I use the `ne` operator?

Here I am comparing with an empty string.

Comment: Eh, because `eq` is for string comparison and `''` is a string?

Comment: here i am comparing with empty string with number right ? It should work na ..why the error

Comment: Is `''` a number? No, so you can't compare it with `!=`.

Comment: Which version of perl are you using?

Comment: You are not using `ne` but it's numeric sibling, and warning says exactly that. (**possible duplicate of** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131701/best-way-to-avoid-isnt-numeric-in-numeric-eq-warning)

Comment: @user3274607, there is no *error*. That is a *warning*. Perl will still add, subtract, multiply by an empty string (0) or make a numerical comparison with it. It's simply warning you this could be a case where the code might not do what you want. Try this out: `my $v = '' + 3; say $v;`

Answer (score 2):

The value `undef` is there specifically so that you can test whether a variable has been defined yet. Initialising a variable to a string when it is to be compared to a number rather defeats this purpose.

You should leave your `$gPrevious` variable *undefined*, and test for that inside your subroutine.

Like this

```
my $gPrevious;

func();

sub func {
  my $localval = 52552;

  unless (defined $gPrevious and $gPrevious == $localval) {
    # x statements;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the '==' or '!=' comparison operator requires having two numbers.

If one of the two is a string that perl can easily make a number such as "1", perl will do what you want and compare the 1.

But: If you compare a string or undef with the '!=' operator, there will be a warning.

In your case, I suggest you simply use

```
$gPrevious = 0;
# ...
if ( $gPrevious != $local_val ){ #...
```

which would get rid of the warning and work fine.

Testing for defined is another possibility, while testing for integers is not trivial.

You could use eq instead, but this is problematic, as then for example '1.0' ne '1'.

Answer (score 0):

Perl provides two separate operators for string comparison (eq/ne) and numeric comparison (==/!=). LHS value must match the type of operator being used. In your case, LHS is a string and you are using a numeric operator for comparison. Hence, the error.